# https//recipe-010-webhook.herokuapp.com?op=webhook .Error - Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid

Tags: spring, heroku, docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

try to run https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-java . weebhook application on heroku . using below Redirect URI Variable

https//recipe-010-webhook.herokuapp.com?op=webhook

--------------------------------Error message --------------------------------------

> Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration:
> 6ff27772-2b0d-4da5-97ea-3c9398e096ac ::
> HTTP/1.1://recipe-010-webhook.herokuapp.com?op=webhook :: ***Error -
> Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.***

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: i m trying execute webhook application. which is  on git hub on below git hub link ::::::::https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-java.                                                                 On final step  we are getting error at back end....: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: 6ff27772-2b0d-4da5-97ea-3c9398e096ac :: HTTP/1.1://recipe-010-webhook.herokuapp.com?op=webhook :: Error - Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.i have configured https//recipe-010-webhook.herokuapp.com?op=webhook  for listener URL...

Answer (score 0):

This code example has been deprecated.
Instead there are two AWS webhook examples showing how to use DocuSign Connect and since you asked for Java:

An updated worker can be found here: https://github.com/docusign/connect-java-worker-aws

An updated listener can be found here: https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-aws